# Execute a method upon clicking stay on page in confirmation dialog on browser close

Tags: javascript

I got to know how we can get a popup when the user tries to close the browser. Now my question how can we execute some piece of code if the user says 'Stay on page'? is there any click handler for that button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `onbeforeunload` event.

```
(function () {

    var oldMousemove = document.body.onmousemove,
        onCancel = function () {
            // Do something if the user stays.
            document.body.onmousemove = oldMousemove;
        };

    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        document.body.onmousemove = onCancel;
        return 'Do you really want to leave?';
    };

})();
```

Note: Most browsers won't respect the custom prompt statement and will favor their own instead.

Comment: am already doing that. it is working fine. My question is how can i execute some thing when the user stays on the page.

Comment: this will give the dialog twice; one is user defined and another is the browser default one. because when you return something from the onbeforeunload handler browser will by default gives that popup

Comment: Also, chrome is not giving any custom popups inside the onbeforeunload handlers, so i think we should avoid custom popups:(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14953/discussion-between-veeru-a-s-and-depot)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
    (function(){
      window.onbeforeunload = function (e) { 
        if(!e) var e = window.event;
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        e.returnValue = false;
        if (e.stopPropagation) {
          e.stopPropagation();
          e.preventDefault();
        }
        return false;
      }
    }());

</script>
```

Works in Firefox and IE 9

Comment: But it doesnt help me to stay on the page

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Andrew.. But my question is how can i execute something on staying back in the page?